# Link UITableView cell to UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

My app creates TableView cells for bookmarks. Can you please tell me how to manage it, that the User can click this cells and then the screen is jumping to a UIWebView which shows him the bookmarked page. Please help me, I'm stucking with this since 72h and I can't find the solution. A code sample would be very useful, I think.

Comment: can you show what you tried ?

Comment: You need to read up on the UITableViewDelegate methods from Apple's docs. Specifically, look at - tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:            and explore your options for presenting your UIWebView from there.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: Your TableView datasource contains a bookmarks array ? could you show the model please, it contains some url property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said your TableView Cells are the bookmarks, then I assume they will be having the saved URL linked to them. If you have the url then you can easily open up that URL in a WebView by creating a request for that URL and loading request in WebView, by using the didSelectRowAtIndexpath of UITableView.